# how to show date, with daterange (2 dates) in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have daterange

```
startdate : 2018-02-20
enddate : 2018-02-28
```

so i want to show date between startdate and enddate
but exclude weekends (saturday and sunday)

the result should:

```
2018-02-20
2018-02-21
2018-02-22
2018-02-23
2018-02-26
2018-02-27
2018-02-28
```

how could i get the result with sql phpmyadmin?

thanks

Comment: i dont think so mysql can do it.. but if mysql can do it, will be curious to know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tableName 
where dateColumn between 'startdate'and 'enddate'
and weekday(dateColumn) not in (5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableName
where dateColumn > startdate 
and dateColumn < enddate
and weekday(dateColumn) in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```